# Windows 7 MSDN version

Tags: windows-7

I recently purchased a copy of Windows 7 online. Upon trying to install, it stopped and I was told that it could not find a 64 bit driver for my CD/DVD and I could not finish install.

I contacted Microsoft and was told that this was something called an MSDN version according to the product key and that was the reason for the problem. They also said is was illegal to sell it to me.

The company I bought it from never returned my calls or emails and luckily I got money back through Amazon. Amazon didn't even want me to send it back. Anyway my question is, is there anyway to load this onto my system and will I have problems or should I just throw it out? Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Just wondering, how does it being an MSDN version affect the ability to finding a driver? I actually am an official MSDN subscription holder and never came across this problem... Anyone?

Comment: This problem is related to a corrupt download 95% of the time. The other 5% is a bad burn job.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately commonsense has to win here: if it's illegal, don't use it. Use the money to buy a real version (this is why I prefer getting stuff from Amazon directly instead of another seller on amazon.com) or if you're a student somewhere you can probably grab it for $50 from your university.

Answer (score 2):

The bottom line is that you don't have the right to use it.  Period.  You got your money back, you can now try to obtain a license through proper channels.  Just destroy it.